# VSCode suggestion shows inappropriate modules instead of suitable properties

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

There is property `label` that can be placed into `theme` object.

When i'm trying to peek object props suggestions with `ctrl + space` -
VSCode returns me trash suggestions I've never even used before.
There is no `label` prop after trying to filter result out:

[image]

Then I delete what I typed and start over without pressing `ctrl + space` and voila - I see `label` property:

[image]

So I can't get know acceptable properties without typing this properties...

What settings need to be set in order to always suggest correct properties ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend to open Settings UI and go over `Text Editor -> Suggestions` section where all suggestion settings are displayed.

You can read their description and configure VS Code to match your expectations.

Comment: It's so obvious.
Could you please point me at particular setting? since I've already tried everything seemed related to my question

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @pluto as I can see you've typed 2 letters and got multiple suggestions, then typed 4 letters and significantly reduced the number of suggestions, which is perfectly reasonable.
Check out the `editor.suggestSelection` setting that defines how suggestions are prioritized. It can remember previously accepted suggestions and put them on top

Comment: Look, there is property `label` that can be placed into `theme` object.

On a first screen I place cursor inside curly braces, press `ctrl + space` to show me available properties and VSCode returns me suggestions some of them I've never even used before (so it's not about priority), then I'm filtering suggestions list with first 2 letters `la` and see no properties that resemble me `label`.

Then I delete what I typed and start over without pressing `ctrl + space` and voila - I see truly acceptable properties.

So I can't get know acceptable properties without typing this properties